# Insert column line working in one macro but not in another

Tags: excel, vba

Very simple code but I'm tearing my hair out.

```
Columns("M:M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

When running in a blank macro on any workbook, it works. When added as a new line in an existing macro for a specific workbook, it doesn't. When running existing macro then new macro in specific workbook, it works. When calling new macro in existing macro, it doesn't.

I havent got a clue how to fix this.

Edit: I can change the cell colour and value without issued, so it's definitely acting on the right book, sheet and cells. It just won't insert a column.

Edit2: I added a colour change and it's acting in the first blank row after the data, no matter what range I specify.

Edit3: I added:

```
Range("M1").Entire column.Interior.Color = 2
Range("M1").Entire column.Insert
```

This turned N1 and N7-N100000+ to black and added a column between U and V.

Edit4: Managed to force it to work by deleting data connections and unlisting then relisting table. Absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: If you don't specify the workbook and worksheet, then the code runs on the Active workbook and active worksheet. If your macro is trying to operate on a specific book & sheet, you should write that. `Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(...`

Comment: It's supposed to run as part of a macro that has already specified the active workbook and sheet. The lines before and after work exactly as intended, but not the insert.